# Symbolicate error in xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports, xcode5.1

My client gave me crash log in ".crash" format and I didn't set anything special in my project settings which detect or may help to catch crash. Now I have ".crash" file and crash happening in iOS 7.0.3 and I want to catch the crash where it happening in Xcode 5.1. I also googled but didn't successful. Kindly guide me that how can I catch the crash where its occurring? Looking for healthy response. Thanks.

Comment: How did you get the crash report? Connected to the device or using some sdk ??

Comment: Your title says "Symbolicate error". I am seeing a problem with XCode 5.1.1 Organizer where the .crash file is not being symbolicated when I import it. Were you trying to see the crash in the Organizer with symbolicated stacks?